# How to install latest catfish in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu

I was trying to install the **latest** catfish from 
https://launchpad.net/catfish-search/+download
on my Ubuntu 10.04 (need this version at the moment, nothing more recent)

The version in apt-get for Ubuntu 10.04 is not sufficient for me at the moment.

Unzipping the archive and doing what is described in the INSTALL file.

but when trying to launch catfish, the following appears:

```
:~$ catfish
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/catfish.py", line 24, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GObject
ImportError: No module named gi.repository
```

So I tried to install http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python3-gi but I can't find this via `aptitude` or `synaptic`.

What to do?

Comment: Upgrade to 12.04...alternately, the non-localized version of this questions is *Does python have a package management system?* to which I believe the answer is yes, [pip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)), which is itself probably in the 10.04 repos.  You should be able to use that to install whatever py lib you want...

Answer (score 1):

From this question:

- [ImportError: No module named gi.repository Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119618/importerror-no-module-named-gi-repository-mac-os-x)

  - pyGTK is for GTK 2 only. If you want the python bindings for GTK 3, you need to install pyGObject.

Use pip or apt:

- [PyGObject 2.28.3 @ PIP](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyGObject/2.28.3)
- Also known as [python-gobject](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/python-importerror-no-module-named-gi-repository-921361/), available for 10.04: [python-gobject @ lucid lynx (10.04)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/python-gobject)

Comment: I used synaptic Package manager to reinstall python-gobject and I used sudo apt-get install python-gobject , but it was already installed

Comment: python3-gobject has become [python3-gi](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/python3-gi/filelist) in newer ubuntus; the linked `python-gobject` refers solely to python2.6 (or 2.7), as it was on Lucid.